# Writing a Python regex given this finite state machine

Tags: python, regex, ply

I'm writing a Java lexer in Python using PLY.

I have this finite state machine:

[image: Regular expression matching state machine]

Its aim should be to match all the line comments in some code. I want to build a Python regex that does exactly what this machine does.

The regex I want to find will be written in a method called `t_IGNORE_LINECOMMENT(t)` so that, while lexing, every line comment will be ignored.

All the similiar regexes that I found have some issues, like this

`(\/\/[^"\n\r]*(?:"[^"\n\r]*"[^"\n\r]*)*[\r\n]|\/\*([^*]|\*(?!\/))*?\*\/)(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)`

that can be tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/2P22mR/2).

This one is supposed to match every kind of comment, but can match also `"//"/"` and fails to match `hey = "//comment" //comment "`, matching all `//comment" //comment "` as a comment and not only `//comment`

In the finite state machine I call `A` all the alphabet and when I write `A/{x,y}`, I mean all of the alphabet except `x` and `y`.

Comment: To exclude characters you use the character class, the [], starting with a ^ which means "not".  so [^xy] Means "not x or y"

Comment: @usr2564301 sorry, i dont know how to add more info for the finite state machine, since i cant post images but only links

Comment: @SteveMapes right, the problem comes out when i want to match `\\line`and `"somestring" \\somecomment somequotes"""`. I need to avoid also to match some comments inside a string like `"\\shouldnt match" \\shouldmatch`

Comment: I meant the external link with your regex – you have included it now, great.

Comment: "all characters except x and y" can be expressed like this [^xy]. That matches a single character that is not x and is not y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:[^"]|"(?:[^\"]|\\.)*")*?(//.*?[\r\n])
```

should do what you want (given [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)): it matches as few as possible non-string characters or strings (themselves any number of non-quote non-escapes or escapes) followed by `//` and as few characters as possible up to the next EOL character.  (The first non-greedy repetition is necessary to cause the comment to be as long as possible.)